# Difference between data section and the bss section in C

Tags: c, unix, process, memory-layout

When checking the disassembly of the object file through the `readelf`, I see the `data` and the `bss` segments contain the same offset address.
The `data` section will contain the initialized global and static variables. BSS will contain un-initialized global and static variables.

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 
  3 static void display(int i, int* ptr);
  4 
  5 int main(){
  6  int x = 5;
  7  int* xptr = &x;
  8  printf("\n In main() program! \n");
  9  printf("\n x address : 0x%x x value : %d  \n",(unsigned int)&x,x);
 10  printf("\n xptr points to : 0x%x xptr value : %d \n",(unsigned int)xptr,*xptr);
 11  display(x,xptr);
 12  return 0;
 13 }
 14 
 15 void display(int y,int* yptr){
 16  char var[7] = "ABCDEF";
 17  printf("\n In display() function  \n");
 18  printf("\n y value : %d y address : 0x%x  \n",y,(unsigned int)&y);
 19  printf("\n yptr points to : 0x%x yptr value : %d  \n",(unsigned int)yptr,*yptr);
 20 }
```

output:

```
   SSS:~$ size a.out 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1311     260       8    1579     62b a.out
```

Here in the above program I don't have any un-initialized data but the BSS has occupied 8 bytes. Why does it occupy 8 bytes?
Also when I disassemble the object file,

> EDITED :

```
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS        00000000 000110 000000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS          00000000 000110 000000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 5] .rodata           PROGBITS        00000000 000110 0000cf 00   A  0   0  4
```

`data`, `rodata` and `bss` has the same offset address. Does it mean the `rodata`, `data` and `bss` refer to the same address?
Do Data section, rodata section and the bss section contain the data values in the same address, if so how to distinguish the data section, bss section and rodata section?

Comment: In C, pointers are printed with %p and an argument cast to `(void*)`.

Comment: "I dont have any un-intialised data but the BSS has occupied 8 bytes" - the libraries that get linked in also have data. In fact, since your program has only local variables and literals, I expect that all the `data` and `bss` sections are from libraries.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `.bss` section is guaranteed to be all zeros when the program is loaded into memory.  So any global data that is uninitialized, or initialized to zero is placed in the `.bss` section. For example:

```
static int g_myGlobal = 0;     // <--- in .bss section
```

The nice part about this is, the `.bss` section data doesn't have to be included in the ELF file on disk (ie. there isn't a whole region of zeros in the file for the `.bss` section). Instead, the loader knows from the section headers how much to allocate for the `.bss` section, and simply zero it out before handing control over to your program.

Notice the `readelf` output:

```
[ 3] .data PROGBITS 00000000 000110 000000 00 WA 0 0 4
[ 4] .bss NOBITS 00000000 000110 000000 00 WA 0 0 4
```

`.data` is marked as `PROGBITS`. That means there are "bits" of program data in the ELF file that the loader needs to read out into memory for you. `.bss` on the  other hand is marked `NOBITS`, meaning there's nothing in the file that needs to be read into memory as part of the load.

---

**Example:**

```
// bss.c
static int g_myGlobal = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `$ gcc -m32 -Xlinker -Map=bss.map -o bss bss.c`

Look at the section headers with `$ readelf -S bss`

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
   :
  [13] .text             PROGBITS        080482d0 0002d0 000174 00  AX  0   0 16
   :
  [24] .data             PROGBITS        0804964c 00064c 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          08049650 000650 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
   :
```

Now we look for our variable in the symbol table: `$ readelf -s bss | grep g_myGlobal`

```
37: 08049654     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 g_myGlobal
```

Note that `g_myGlobal` is shown to be a part of section 25. If we look back in the section headers, we see that 25 is `.bss`.

---

**To answer your real question:**

> Here in the above program I dont have any un-intialised data but the BSS has occupied 8 bytes. Why does it occupy 8 bytes ?

Continuing with my example, we look for any symbol in section 25:

```
$ readelf -s bss | grep 25
     9: 0804825c     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 
    25: 08049650     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 
    32: 08049650     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 completed.5745
    37: 08049654     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 g_myGlobal
```

The third column is the size.  We see our expected 4-byte `g_myGlobal`, and this 1-byte `completed.5745`. This is probably a function-static variable from somewhere in the C runtime initialization - remember, a lot of "stuff" happens before `main()` is ever called.

4+1=5 bytes. However, if we look back at the `.bss` section header, we see the last column `Al` is 4. That is the section alignment, meaning this section, when loaded, will always be a multiple of 4 bytes.  The next multiple up from 5 is 8, and that's why the `.bss` section is 8 bytes.

---

**Additionally** We can look at the map file generated by the linker to see what object files got placed where in the final output.

```
.bss            0x0000000008049650        0x8
 *(.dynbss)
 .dynbss        0x0000000000000000        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/crt1.o
 *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
 .bss           0x0000000008049650        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/crt1.o
 .bss           0x0000000008049650        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/crti.o
 .bss           0x0000000008049650        0x1 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/32/crtbegin.o
 .bss           0x0000000008049654        0x4 /tmp/ccKF6q1g.o
 .bss           0x0000000008049658        0x0 /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS)
 .bss           0x0000000008049658        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/32/crtend.o
 .bss           0x0000000008049658        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/crtn.o
```

Again, the third column is the size.

We see 4 bytes of `.bss` came from `/tmp/ccKF6q1g.o`. In this trivial example, we know that is the temporary object file from the compilation of our bss.c file.  The other 1 byte came from `crtbegin.o`, which is part of the C runtime.

---

Finally, since we know that this 1 byte mystery bss variable is from `crtbegin.o`, and it's named `completed.xxxx`, it's real name is `completed` and it's probably a static inside some function.  Looking at [`crtstuff.c`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/222d5c496e3713cc2fa46d0ff24ca111ca2fcc95/libgcc/crtstuff.c#L373) we find the culprit: a `static _Bool completed` inside of `__do_global_dtors_aux()`.

Comment: I would not initialize the example `static int g_myGlobal;` -to be sure it goes to `.bss`-  and it should be used in the code, otherwise the compiler could optimize by removing it entirely.

Comment: More likely, the .bss comes from some internal variable in the included standard libraries, probably from printf. Which is why printf et al aren't thread safe.

Comment: @Lundin `printf` is going to be part of `libc`, which is dynamically linked - so its bss won't show up in this executable. Also, I can't think of any reason `printf` in particular would keep any state.

Comment: @Lundin Besides, I explicitly showed that the other 1 byte was from `crtbegin.o`.  Some minimal CRT startup code is always going to be statically linked.

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart: `stdout` is used by `printf` and obviously has some state.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being pedantic, but that's stdout, not printf. Regardless this is all libc so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

By definition, the [bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment takes some place in memory (when the program starts) but don't need any disk space. You need to define some variable to get it filled, so try

```
int bigvar_in_bss[16300];
int var_in_data[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

<sup>Your simple program might not have any data in `.bss`, and shared libraries (like `libc.so`) may have "their own `.bss`"</sup>

File offsets and memory addresses are not easily related.

Read more about the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) specification, also use `/proc/` (eg `cat /proc/self/maps` would display the address space of the `cat` process running that command).
Read also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)